# List of apps/products using ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-autoquery

ServiceStack authors/community: you have done impressive job!

Outside of SO, I was wondering if there is an up to date list of products/apps using ServiceStack?

Or maybe ServiceStack app/architectural patterns for larger apps (with MQ) ? I looked at some of the suggested demo apps in SS github and I might have missed it if there is any, but just looking for something bigger/larger to explore apps with big numbers of domains. Maybe a fake subscription saas online app for some fictional rest API ? ...

I obviously am after reference materials to have SS in the list of contender framework for an upcoming project.

Anyways I hope I didn't miss a reference from SS large amount of documentation!

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow isn't the right place to ask non-technical questions like this, you can try the [Google+ ServiceStack Community](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/112445368900682590445) if you're not a Customer, or the [ServiceStack Customer Forums](https://forums.servicestack.net/) if you are.

I previously answered a question similar on broadly [Who's using ServiceStack](https://plus.google.com/u/0/107069789106008902235/posts/EbpKVD6xnCd) in January 2015, since then ServiceStack Customer base has grown considerably where we have several Fortune 500 Customers, unfortunately we're not able to disclose any specific Customer info as we have several NDA's with large companies prohibiting any disclosure which we've extended as a matter of policy to never disclose any of our Customer details for Marketing purposes or otherwise.

So for specifics you'll need to [ask the Google Community directly](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/112445368900682590445) where some of our Customers may volunteer their info themselves.

Comment: Thank you I will make sure to gather up info from Google+ and any other means to get references. The feature list continually growing seems to be a good point as well.

Answer (score 1):

A good starting point is to study ServiceStack apps in [GitHub](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps).